# jquery autocomplete results

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have a webservice

```
[Serializable]
    public class DataObject
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }


    [WebMethod]
    public DataObject[] GetCities(string q, int limit)
    {
        // A collection to hold our results
        List<DataObject> customers = new List<DataObject>();

        // Our source of names, could be a DB query
        string[] db = new string[]{"aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","ddsads","asdsad","asdsad","dsfsfd"};

        // Looping through the datasource to select the items that match
        int i=0;
        foreach(string cust in db)
        {

            if(cust.ToLower().StartsWith(q.ToLower()))
            {
                i++;
                customers.Add(new DataObject { Description = cust, ID = i });
            }
        }

        // Return the items that contained the text in alphabetical order
        return customers.ToArray();

    }
```

Javascript:

```
// and in my javascript I use jquery autocomplete like this 
$("#txtCity").autocomplete("Autocomplete.asmx/GetCities", { dataType: "xml", datakey: "Description", max: 5 });
```

the question is:
how can I get in javascript the ID of the item selected in the autocomplete?
I want to pass it to another function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a results handler:

```
$("#txtCity").autocomplete("<Your existing stuff here>").result(
         function(event, item, formatted)
         {
            // Use the item property
         }
      );
```

Comment: which js do I need to make it work ? 
cause I get error "object doesnt support .... "

10X

Comment: You need jquery.autocomplete.js and jquery.js.

Comment: no still the same error ...
but I tried to use :

 formatItem: function(data, i, max) {
                    debugger;
                    return data.Desc ;
                },

                formatResult: function(data, data2) {
                    //debugger;
                    //alert(data)
                }

and it works, but the data allwaya contains only the "Description" and not the "ID" ,could it be cause I'm calling autocomplete only with datakey: "Description" ?

Answer (score 0):

i found what i needed in

[Formatting data for jQuery Autocomplete results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927766/formatting-data-for-jquery-autocomplete-results)

10X

and the event is "result" not "results" .... 10X man !!